# Windows shortcut for connect device through WIFI to Android studio for debug?

Tags: android-studio

I have problem to connect device to Android Studio over `WIFI` by every time below code writing in command prompt. Is there any windows shortcut for execute code in command  prompt and need to connect device to Android Studio for debug my Application. It would be nice...

I write every time to connect device  to Android Studio:

```
Connect the device via USB and make sure debugging is working.
adb tcpip 5555
find the IP address with adb shell netcfg
adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555
Disconnect USB and proceed with wireless debugging.
adb -s <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555 usb to switch back when done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching many hours, I found solution. To get connect your device to Android Studio follow these steps:

**Steps:**

1. Connect device to Android Studio.(When PC starts only).
2. Keep/paste following file on Desktop.
3. Change this file as you need,  i.e., change IP address
4. Then save and run that file by double clicking on it.

File is **`CoonectDevice.bat`**

```
cd\
cd c:
cd C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>
```